# sklearn ValueError: Input contains NaN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

ValueError: Input contains NaN
i have run

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoderfrom
data_.iloc[:,1:-1] = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(data_.iloc[:,1:-1])
```

here is data_

```
    Age     Sex Embarked  Survived
0  22.0    male        S         0
1  38.0  female        C         2
2  26.0  female        S         2
3  35.0  female        S         2
4  35.0    male        S         0
```

Comment: You need to perform imputation - i.e. replace the Nulls

Comment: See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

Before doing some processor, you have always have to to preprocess the data and make a few summary of how your data is. In concrete, the error you obtained is telling you that you have NaN values. To check it, try this command:

```
df.isnull().any().any()
```

If the output is **TRUE**, you have NaN values. You can run the next command if you want to know where this NaN values are:

```
df.isnull().any()
```

Then, you will know in which column are your NaN values.

Once you know you have NaN values, you have to preprocess them (eliminate, fill,... whatever you believe is the best option). The link *gtomer* commented is a nice resource.